# Why is $X_T \mathbb{1}_{T <t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge T}$ measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I was trying to understand the proof of Theorem 18 in Chapter 1 of the book on Stochastic Integration by Protter and there is some thing I don't understand

Why is $X_T \mathbb{1}_{T <t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge T}$
It is being used in the 4th line of the proof. I see that we can write 
$$X_T \text{ as } X_{t \wedge T} \text{ on the set } \mathbb{1}_{T<t} $$
and then it comes out of the conditional expectation since $X_{t \wedge T}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge T}$ measurable since X is adapted and cadlag. But I somehow do not see why can I take the indicator function outside the conditional expectation. It seems impossible that one can do that.I am totally stuck .
Moreover the statement in the proof
$\text{ However }H \in \mathcal{F}_t \implies H \mathbb{1}_{T \geq t} \in \mathcal{F}_T$ doesnt make sense to me since its a product of a set and random variable(indicator).

Can someone give me a hint why it is true?

[image]

Comment: $1_{T<t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}$-measurable. Don't we always know by time $t\wedge T$ whether $T<t$ or not? (Since $T$ is a stopping time.)

Comment: @ spaceisdarkgreen. Ah i see but we need the right continuity of the filtration for this to work. Right?

Comment: I don't think it needs right-continuity. Is $\{T< t\}$ not always in $\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}$ when $T$ is a stopping time? It's always in $\mathcal{F_t}$ and $t\wedge T\le t.$ Also with regard to your other question, they are probably using $H\in \mathcal{F_t}$ to mean $H$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable RV.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you very much I got confused with the theorem that  $\{ T <t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ iff T is stopping time when the filtration is right continuous. But we indeed do not need right continuity here. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. You'd need right continuity to prove the other direction of that iff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both $T,T\wedge t$ are stoping times, $1_{T<t}=1_{T\wedge t<t}\in\mathscr{F}_{T\wedge t}$ and $$X_T1_{T<t}=X_{T\wedge t}1_{T<t}=X_{T\wedge t }1_{T\wedge t<t}\in\mathscr{F}_{T\wedge t},$$
therefore $$\mathsf{E}[X_T1_{T<t}|\mathscr{F}_{T\wedge t}]=X_T1_{T<t}.$$